# Intel compiler cannot vectorize this simple loop?

Tags: c++, vectorization

So I have the following code which seems very simple to me:

```
#define MODS_COUNT 5

int start1 = <calc at runtime>;
int start2 = <calc at runtime>;

for (int j=0; j<MODS_COUNT; j++) // loop 5 times doing simple addition.
    logModifiers[start1 +  j] += logModsThis[start2 + j];
```

This loop is part of an outer loop (not sure if this makes a difference)

The compiler says:
`message : loop was not vectorized: vectorization possible but seems inefficient.`

Why can't this loop be vectorised? it seems very simple to me. How can I force vectorisation and check performance myself?

I have Intel C++ Compiler 2013 update 3.

Full code is here if anyone is interested: http://pastebin.com/Z6H5ZejW

Edit: I understand that the compiler decided that it's inefficient. I'm asking:

Why is it inefficient?

How can I force it so that I can benchmark myself?

Edit2: If I change it to 4 instead of 5 then it gets vectorised. What makes 5 inefficient? I thought it can be done in 2 instructions, the first does 4 and the second is "normal" does 1, instead of 5 instructions.

Comment: And you mean to say that you think that the compiler is wrong with "seems inefficient"? I would tend to agree, that a loop of 5 items would probably not be very efficient to vectorise.

Comment: The compiler doesn't tell you that the loop cannot be vectorised.  Personally I think that compilers which choose to (dis)obey programmers as they (the compilers) think fit are probably a very good idea.

Comment: Most likely the data isn't organised in memory in a way directly suitable for using vector instructions on it and the compiler has determined that the cost of rearranging the data is more than the time saved by operating on more of it at the same time.

Comment: try `6` and `7` times.

Comment: Depending on start1 and start2 values your data may or may not be computed in parallel, because next loop iteration may use previous

Comment: @kassak start1 and start2 are constant during the loop. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Koushik 6 and 7 don't vectorise. 4 and 8 do.

Comment: @Spacemonkey is it that multiples of 4 are being vectorized?

Comment: Assume: start2=0 and start1=1 => n-th element needs (n-1)-th element

Comment: @kassak I don't understand what you are saying. Why does the start matter?

Comment: 5 iterations is definitely too few to be worth vectorizing. Don't forget that there is a LOT of overhead in vectorizing (alignment checks, loop peeling, etc.). These add up. So unless you have a LOT of iterations to do, or the data has been perfectly setup to avoid the overhead, it won't be worth vectorizing.

Answer (score 2):

According to vectorization in intel compilers :

There are SIMD(Single instruction multiple data) registers which are 128 byte long. so if sizeof(int) is `4` then `4` integers can sit in these registers and a single instruction can perform on these `4` `int`s.(this also depends if same type of operation is done on these `int`s, here its true. more over each element of the array on LHS is dependant on a different element of a different array.)

if there are 8 `int`s then two instructions are required.(instead of 8 without vectorization).

but if 5(or 6 or 7) `int`s are there then that too will require two instructions. which `might` be not better than without vectorization code.

further reading [LINK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/a-guide-to-auto-vectorization-with-intel-c-compilers).

Comment: Why two instructions for a loop of 5 is not better? isn't 2 instructions faster than 5?

Comment: @Spacemonkey but the computation on the 5th does not need the SIMD register. which might be heavier compared to having all of them computed without vectorization(if 5 were vectorized). To be careful intel does not say that time required to execute vectorially is not `1/4` times without vectorization. it just says 1 instruction.

Comment: benching marking your code(with such small loop) will be a challenge . Too high a loop count, the compiler with straight out vectorizes it. too small will be hard to differentiate.

Comment: If loop count size = 1024, then *A good compiler will optimize this loop by using vector operations when the SSE2 or later
instruction set is specified. The code will read four elements of b into a 128-bit vector
register, do an addition with another vector register containing (2,2,2,2), and store the four
results in a. This operation will then be repeated 1024/4 = 256 times and the speed will be improved by a factor 4 in the best cases.It is best when the loop count is divisible by the
number of elements per vector. * (from *Optimizing software in C++
An optimization guide* By Agner Fog.)

Comment: @SChepurin yes but here in this particular code we are talking about a very small count which is what is interesting. each cycle counts. By the way it would be good to know how many cycles it takes to execute on the SIMD register. that will clear all doubts surrounding this issue.

Comment: @Koushik -Yes. I just wanted to say that you seem to point in the right direction.

Comment: @SChepurin you had another comment which you deleted. did you quote from the same source that you quoted the second? if not can you tell me the source? i hope these source are free to read?

Comment: @Koushik - I simply wanted to improve the quote. Yes, it is free source -http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf. Wish you a good reading of *Optimizing software in C++ 
An optimization guide for Windows, Linux and Mac 
platforms* 
By Agner Fog.

Comment: @SChepurin thanks a lot:). This i feel is a very important doc

Answer (score 0):

For vectorization to make sense the most inner loop has to have a large enough trip count. In your case it is small, and the compiler calculates according to its cost model that the speedups due to vectorization would be small, or negative.

I've seen wonders when did loop interchange - exchanged the inner and outer loop so that the most inner loops has a large trip count.